# profiling, How to avoid FPU (hardware) in VS pro 2008 or 2012RC and use emulated FPU codes

Tags: cortex-m

I need to optimise some codes for **Cortex-M3** processor which doesn't have FP unit. I'm completely new to domain of optimisation.anyways,I use **VS 2012 Release Candidate** for native compiling  of codes on my pc(**Intel Core i5**, **windows 7** as os)and then porting them to Cortex_M3.I tried to write my codes in a way that it uses **as little as possible the floating point arithmetics**.but I still have a few. so i know that when i embedd it in Cortex_M3, it will take advantage of emulated FPU codes instead (**Software FPU**). Since i'm not able to **do profiling for cortex_m3**, i did it on my PC using VS2012 (Instrumentation method) to verify which functions take more time and have to be more optimized.
I think that profiling results on my PC can be proportional to that of COrtex_M3 if i don't use FP unit of my PC.
Is there a keyword or way in Visual Studio (2008 pro. or 2012 RC) which allows me to skip the (hardware) FP unit?

your insights are very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your PC is soooooo different to a Cortex M3 that optimisations performed there are unlikely to be of any relevance.  Some of the differences:

- PC can issue more than one instruction per cycle
- PC has some billion of those cycles per second vs some tens of millions
- PC likely has more cache than your M3 has RAM
- As you observe - the floating point unit

The M3 is an embedded processor - if you can't profile in the traditional way either get a better toolset, so that you *can*, or do it by hand, by using the hardware timers in the device to time your functions.  Or toggle some port pins and hang an oscilloscope off it - that's  proper embedded :)

EDIT:

---

You *can* profile without an OS - higher-end embedded toolchains can instrument the code, run it and pull the results back for post-processing

---

There are other hardware timers than the watchdog.  At the simplest level, write some functions to read the value before you perform some task, read the value afterwards, subtract the result and print it out. More complex schemes can also be done, logging many iterations and keeping track of statistics etc.

---

If you have a few port pins, just set one before the function(s) you want to profile, clear it when it completes.

With a 4 channel scope you can see the execution times (and when they happen relative to each other, which can be useful if one interrupts another) of 4 sections of code at a time.  If you have more, get a logic analyser and you can do loads of them!

You can also see the jitter or variation in execution time which can be instructive.  Try it on the libc trig functions as the angle varies, you'll see that at some angles the sin/cos functions (for example) take way longer to run than at other angles.  This can be a significant problem in a real-time system.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reponse.Regarding your recommendations from my understanding

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reponse.Regarding your recommendations from my understanding 1-Since there is no OS on my COrtex M3, i can not profile it via the traditional way. 2-The HardWare timer, is it the watchdog timer?if so, it can just show the duration of my entire application and not internal functions. Am I right? 3-I love the i dea of using Scope.Do you mean that i associate i.e return values of my funcs. to some free pins of cortex M3 (if it exists!) and track them on a scope when their values changes?  thanks